# PHP Sort Multi-Tired ARRAY by multiple sorts?

Tags: php

i have an php array of sports scores and i want to sort by the following

Wins Desc, Ties Desc, Points Scored Desc, Points Allowed Asc

anyone know how i can do this?

This array was generated by multiple mysql quires

```
[14] => Array
    (
        [title] => Crushers
        [team_color] => #0000ff
        [wins] => 0
        [losses] => 1
        [ties] => 1
        [pointsscored] => 18
        [pointsallowed] => 19
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [title] => Purple Stars
        [team_color] => #ae25d9
        [wins] => 1
        [losses] => 1
        [ties] => 0
        [pointsscored] => 20
        [pointsallowed] => 21
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [title] => Lighting Boltz
        [team_color] => #d6c128
        [wins] => 0
        [losses] => 0
        [ties] => 2
        [pointsscored] => 12
        [pointsallowed] => 12
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [title] => The Black Cheetahs
        [team_color] => #000000
        [wins] => 1
        [losses] => 0
        [ties] => 1
        [pointsscored] => 15
        [pointsallowed] => 13
    )
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has an answer as [comment on PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#100534).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a function to sort every multidimensional array by one of his columns ,look at `array_multisort()` and customize this function to your need:

```
 function sortArrayBy($array , $column_name,$sort=SORT_DESC){

    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
      $column[$key]  = $row[$column_name];
    }

    array_multisort($column, $sort, $array);
    return $array;

}
```

Call it like this :

```
<?php sortArrayBy($yourArray,'date') ; ?>
```

Comment: thank you that worked great i just added in the extra constraints to the  array_multisort